# Can I use a type from reflection as a type parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, generic-method

Can I use a type from reflection as a type parameter? E.g. I want to pick a persister based on a passed object:

```
IPersister GetPersisterFor(IEntity entity)
{
    return GetPersisterFor<entity.GetType()>(); // <-- this cannot be compiled
}

IPersister GetPersisterFor<TEntity>() where TEntity : IEntity
{
    //some logic to get persister...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only via reflection; you would need to use `GetMethod` to get the `MethodInfo` for the generic method, then call `MakeGenericMethod(entity.GetType()).Invoke(this, null);` on that.

However, easier is to cheat via dynamic:

```
IPersister Evil<T>(T obj) where T : IEntity {
    return GetPersisterFor<T>();
}
```

And make the first method just:

```
return Evil((dynamic)entity);
```

This is then a dynamic expression which will detect the correct T to use (to call Evil-of-T) for you.

Note: the only reason you need an extra method is to make sure it doesn't resolve back to itself recursively, since the names are the same.

Comment: any reason why you call it Evil? :)

Comment: @Rhys because I needed to call it something :)

Comment: +1 Alternatively, you could just push the generic type parameter `T` up the call tree.  At some point, the exact type of `entity` is probably known, so if all methods from that point down to `GetPersisterFor` retained `T` as a generic type, you wouldn't need to use `dynamic`.  If that isn't possible (the top-level caller only has a variable of type `IYo` available), then this is a great shortcut to the `MakeGenericMethod` solutions.

Comment: +1 Cool. I didn't know the dynamic type can be used like this :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to get the generic method definition.
After that you can use [`MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod.aspx) to construct the generic method.

So something like:

```
MethodInfo genericMethodDefinition = GetType()
    .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    .Where(method => method.IsGenericMethod && method.Name == "GetPersisterFor")
    .First();

// OR

MethodInfo genericMethodDefinition = GetType().GetMethod("GetPersisterFor",
    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, Type.EmptyTypes, null);

// THEN

MethodInfo genericMethod = genericMethodDefinition.MakeGenericMethod(entity.GetType());
genericMethod.Invoke(this, null);
```

Comment: You'll need a bit more in GetMethod, to a: access non-public methods, and b: disambiguate between the generic and non-generic method of the same name

Answer (score 1):

Because both generic and non generic methods have same name, you have to iterate over all methods of class to find proper one, and then invoke it:

```
public IPersister GetPersisterFor(IEntity entity)
{       
    MethodInfo getPersisterForGenericMethod = 
                    GetType().GetMethods()
                        // iterate over all methods to find proper generic implementation
                        .Single(methodInfo => methodInfo.Name == "GetPersisterFor" && methodInfo.IsGenericMethod)
                        // supply it with generic type parameter
                        .MakeGenericMethod(entity.GetType());

    // invoke it
    return getPersisterForGenericMethod.Invoke(this, null) as IPersister;
}

public IPersister GetPersisterFor<TEntity>() where TEntity : IEntity
{
    return null;
}
```

ps: full source code available at [gist.github](https://gist.github.com/4379572)